# On changing navigation (pages) and returning back some data vanishes

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface

Below is the code that I have tried. I have also attached created the video  [Click here to see Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kSGUpmVTmwE) .
My issue is that after selecting product and related scheme and going to next page and then come back to the page the scheme vanishes which should not happen. I have 4 layers of navigation and when navigating to 2nd level I have the option to choose products and if the product has scheme the popup occurs and when selecting the scheme the scheme shows in the 2nd page but if I go to the 3rd page and then return to the 2nd page only the product remains, the related scheme product column vanishes.

```
  Obx(() { 
              return ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  itemCount: salesController.currentOrderItems.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  
                    if (schemeMsgController.text.isNotEmpty) {
                      //Scheme Layout Builder
                      schemeTitleController.text =
                          salesController.currentOrderItems[index].title;
                      schemeNetPriceController.text =
                          salesController.currentOrderItems[index].netRate;
                      String quantity =
                          salesController.currentOrderItems[index].qty;
                      double schemeRawQuantity = (double.parse(quantity) / 5);
                      if (schemeRawQuantity > 50) {}
                      int schemeQuantity = schemeRawQuantity.toInt();
                      schemeQuantityController.text = schemeQuantity.toString();

                      //return Text(salesController.currentOrderItems[index].title);
                      return Column(
                        children: [
                          CreateOrderTiles(
                              orders: salesController.currentOrderItems[index]),
                           // Scheme UI
                          Card(
                            color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.1),
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: Column(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                                children: [
                                  Text(
                                    //schemeTitleController.text,
                                    salesController.currentProductTitle,
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment:
                                        MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                    children: [
                                      Text(schemeQuantityController.text +
                                          " pcs"),
                                      Text("Rs: " +
                                          schemeNetPriceController.text),
                                      Text("0.00"),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      );
                      

                    } else {

                      return CreateOrderTiles(
                          orders: salesController.currentOrderItems[index]);
                    }
                  });
                  })
```

Below is the controller code:

```
class SalesController extends GetxController {
  var isLoading = false.obs;
  var orderList = <OrdersModel>[].obs;

  var ordersItems = <OrdersModel>[].obs;
  var currentOrder;
  var availableStock = 0.0.obs;
  var currentProductID = '';
  var currentProductTitle = '';
  var currentProductModel = '';

  var grandTotal = 0.0.obs;
  var totalAmount = 0.0.obs;

  var currentOrderItems = <OrderItemModel>[].obs;

  final TextEditingController productTitleController =
      TextEditingController(text: '0');
  final TextEditingController qtyController = TextEditingController(text: '0');
  final TextEditingController qtySchemeController =
      TextEditingController(text: '0');
  final TextEditingController mrpController = TextEditingController(text: '0');
  final TextEditingController discountController =
      TextEditingController(text: '0');
  final TextEditingController netRateController =
      TextEditingController(text: '0');
  final TextEditingController amountController =
      TextEditingController(text: '0');

  void fetchUserOrders() async {
    isLoading(true); // isLoading.value = true;
    try {
      var orders = await SalesService.getUserOrder(12, 66, '');

      if (orders != null) {
        orderList.value = orders;
      }
    } finally {
      isLoading(false);
    }
    isLoading(false);
  }

  void resetFormFields() {
    productTitleController.text = "";
    qtyController.text = '0';
    mrpController.text = '0';
    discountController.text = '0';
    netRateController.text = '0';
    amountController.text = '0';
  }

  double getPercentValue(String myDiscount) {
    if (myDiscount == '') return 0.0;
    var pos = myDiscount.indexOf('%');
    if (pos < 0) {
      return double.parse(myDiscount);
    } else {
      return (double.parse(myDiscount.replaceAll('%', '')) / 100) *
          double.parse(mrpController.text);
    }
  }

  void addItemToOrder(bool isScheme) {
    // print(currentProductID);
    OrderItemModel orderItem = new OrderItemModel(
      key: Random().toString(),
      productID: currentProductID,
      image: Image.network(''),
      title: currentProductTitle,
      qty: qtyController.text,
      mrp: amountController.text,
      discount: discountController.text,
      netRate: netRateController.text,
      amount: amountController.text,
      isScheme: isScheme,
      ofSchemekey: '',
      modelNumber: currentProductModel,
    );
    currentOrderItems.value.add(orderItem);

    double totalGross = 0.0;
    currentOrderItems.refresh();
    for (var i = 0; i < currentOrderItems.value.length; i++) {
      totalGross += double.parse(currentOrderItems.value[i].amount);
    }

    print('total amount');
    print(totalGross);
    grandTotal.value = totalGross;
    totalAmount.value = totalGross;
  }

  void calculateScheme() {
    double data = double.parse(qtyController.text);
    int qtyScheme = data ~/ 5;
    qtySchemeController.text = qtyScheme.toString();
  }

  void updateProductRowCalc() {
    calculateScheme();
    double total =
        double.parse(qtyController.text) * double.parse(mrpController.text);
    double discount = getPercentValue(discountController.text);
    double netRate = double.parse(mrpController.text) - discount;
    double amount = double.parse(qtyController.text) * netRate;
    netRateController.text = netRate.toString();
    amountController.text = amount.toString();
  }
}
```

Comment: can you provide the controller's code, also check whether the controller is permanent or not, cause once you left the page the controller will be destroyed, causing the values to vanish. in addition use .obs for Observe-able List

Comment: I added the controller code @C.MTalha

Comment: Remove final keyword from controllers, mark your GetxController as permanent

Comment: Another solution is to use RestorationMixin, for that you need to pass the values you want to retain in the page storage bucket, this will cause your page to restore from its previous state https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RestorationMixin-mixin.html

Answer (score 0):

```
SalesController saleController = Get.put(SalesController(), permanent : true);
```

I believe the problem is with the state, once you pushed to another screen, The getx library thinks your controller is unnecessary and destroys it, to retain the values use a permanent flag to retain the value as long as you need, once your controller has finished its purpose, make sure to destroy it, otherwise, it would add unnecessary over head to the app performance.

Answer (score 0):

Remove final from the TextEditingControllers